# Are the apps coded differently for android and windows?

Tags: android

Are the source code for the apps like from google play store  different for installation on an android phone and on a windows pc >

Comment: Android is Java, Windows store is C. Any application NOT from the windows store can be any language. Windows is .exe, .jar and a load of other file endings, while android is .apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android apps are coded in Java using mostly Android Studio
Windows and/or windows phone are coded in C# using Visual Studio

now Microsoft introduced XAMARIN which allows you to code an App only one time using C# and then launched to multiple platforms like Android, WinPhone, iOS, Win desktop...

Answer (score 0):

Android apps are coded in Java and compiled into .apk files that are delivered in Google Play. Other Platforms like Windows and iOS use different programming languages and binary formats for their apps.

However, there are alternatives like [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) that allow you to target multiple platforms with one code base.

Comment: libGDX also allows you to target several platforms